# input type="range" leaves black border when clicked on ipad

Tags: css, ipad

I have a  on my page and I have styled it with css.

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #1b2b66;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: url("../images/slider.png");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  border: 0px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

The issues is: on the ipad when the user clicks the slider thumb a black border surrounds the image. How do I hide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. First of all thank you everyone for the help.

I forgot to set the `background-color:` property. I set it to `#FFF` and now have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `modernizr` to perform a feature detect.

```
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script>Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.inputtypes.range,
  nope: ['use your css to define the range input format']
});
</script>
```

This test looks for  support. When it fails, it loads your css to format that input. If a browser has support for this tag, which means there will be a standard way it renders that control and your css will be redundant. In this case, we usually just let the browser ignore our css settings.

If you really want to override the default css settings. Try using `!important`.

```
border: 0 !important;
```

Comment: I know the image and style works on the iPad. How would the feature detect help me?

Comment: If Safari knows how to render `<input type="range">`, we usually do not try to override their appearance.